Wheels always spinning in the same direction with ros2_control and DiffDriveArduino
I have reached the Articulated Robotics tutorial on ros2_control for real robots (link), but, when I test it, regardless of which teleop_twist_keyboard key I press, all the wheels spin in the same direction! This already rules out any wiring issues, although that's the same as in the video. My robot has 4 wheels instead of 2, but all I did was wire both wheels on each side to each one of the 2 driver terminals. I left the Arduino (ros_arduino_bridge) code intact, and changed some stuff in the diffdrive_arduino plugin to publish hardware interfaces for all 4 wheels. In case those are the issue, here they are:
diffdrive_arduino.cpp:
#include "diffdrive_arduino/diffdrive_arduino.h"


#include "hardware_interface/types/hardware_interface_type_values.hpp"




DiffDriveArduino::DiffDriveArduino()
    : logger_(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveArduino"))
{}





return_type DiffDriveArduino::configure(const hardware_interface::HardwareInfo & info)
{
  if (configure_default(info) != return_type::OK) {
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  RCLCPP_INFO(logger_, "Configuring...");

  time_ = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

  cfg_.FL_wheel_name = info_.hardware_parameters["FL_wheel_name"];
  cfg_.FR_wheel_name = info_.hardware_parameters["FR_wheel_name"];
  cfg_.RL_wheel_name = info_.hardware_parameters["RL_wheel_name"];
  cfg_.RR_wheel_name = info_.hardware_parameters["RR_wheel_name"];
  cfg_.loop_rate = std::stof(info_.hardware_parameters["loop_rate"]);
  cfg_.device = info_.hardware_parameters["device"];
  cfg_.baud_rate = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["baud_rate"]);
  cfg_.timeout = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["timeout"]);
  cfg_.enc_counts_per_rev = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["enc_counts_per_rev"]);

  // Set up the wheels
  fl_wheel_.setup(cfg_.FL_wheel_name, cfg_.enc_counts_per_rev);
  fr_wheel_.setup(cfg_.FR_wheel_name, cfg_.enc_counts_per_rev);
  rl_wheel_.setup(cfg_.RL_wheel_name, cfg_.enc_counts_per_rev);
  rr_wheel_.setup(cfg_.RR_wheel_name, cfg_.enc_counts_per_rev);

  // Set up the Arduino
  arduino_.setup(cfg_.device, cfg_.baud_rate, cfg_.timeout);  

  RCLCPP_INFO(logger_, "Finished Configuration");

  status_ = hardware_interface::status::CONFIGURED;
  return return_type::OK;
}

std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> DiffDriveArduino::export_state_interfaces()
{
  // We need to set up a position and a velocity interface for each wheel

  std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> state_interfaces;

  state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(fl_wheel_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &fl_wheel_.vel));
  state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(fl_wheel_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION, &fl_wheel_.pos));
  state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(fr_wheel_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &fr_wheel_.vel));
  state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(fr_wheel_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION, &fr_wheel_.pos));
  state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(rl_wheel_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &rl_wheel_.vel));
  state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(rl_wheel_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION, &rl_wheel_.pos));
  state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(rr_wheel_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &rr_wheel_.vel));
  state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(rr_wheel_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION, &rr_wheel_.pos));

  return state_interfaces;
}

std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> DiffDriveArduino::export_command_interfaces()
{
  // We need to set up a velocity command interface for each wheel

  std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> command_interfaces;

  command_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::CommandInterface(fl_wheel_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &fl_wheel_.cmd));
  command_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::CommandInterface(fr_wheel_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &fr_wheel_.cmd));
  command_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::CommandInterface(rl_wheel_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &rl_wheel_.cmd));
  command_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::CommandInterface(rr_wheel_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &rr_wheel_.cmd));

  return command_interfaces;
}


return_type DiffDriveArduino::start()
{
  RCLCPP_INFO(logger_, "Starting Controller...");

  arduino_.sendEmptyMsg();
  // arduino.setPidValues(9,7,0,100);
  // arduino.setPidValues(14,7,0,100);
  arduino_.setPidValues(30, 20, 0, 100);

  status_ = hardware_interface::status::STARTED;

  return return_type::OK;
}

return_type DiffDriveArduino::stop()
{
  RCLCPP_INFO(logger_, "Stopping Controller...");
  status_ = hardware_interface::status::STOPPED;

  return return_type::OK;
}

hardware_interface::return_type DiffDriveArduino::read()
{

  // TODO fix chrono duration

  // Calculate time delta
  auto new_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::chrono::duration<double> diff = new_time - time_;
  double deltaSeconds = diff.count();
  time_ = new_time;


  if (!arduino_.connected())
  {
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  arduino_.readEncoderValues(fl_wheel_.enc, fr_wheel_.enc);
  arduino_.readEncoderValues(rl_wheel_.enc, rr_wheel_.enc);

  double pos_prev = fl_wheel_.pos;
  fl_wheel_.pos = fl_wheel_.calcEncAngle();
  fl_wheel_.vel = (fl_wheel_.pos - pos_prev) / deltaSeconds;

  pos_prev = fr_wheel_.pos;
  fr_wheel_.pos = fr_wheel_.calcEncAngle();
  fr_wheel_.vel = (fr_wheel_.pos - pos_prev) / deltaSeconds;
  
  pos_prev = rl_wheel_.pos;
  rl_wheel_.pos = rl_wheel_.calcEncAngle();
  rl_wheel_.vel = (rl_wheel_.pos - pos_prev) / deltaSeconds;

  pos_prev = rr_wheel_.pos;
  rr_wheel_.pos = rr_wheel_.calcEncAngle();
  rr_wheel_.vel = (rr_wheel_.pos - pos_prev) / deltaSeconds;



  return return_type::OK;

  
}

hardware_interface::return_type DiffDriveArduino::write()
{

  if (!arduino_.connected())
  {
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  arduino_.setMotorValues(fl_wheel_.cmd / fl_wheel_.rads_per_count / cfg_.loop_rate, rl_wheel_.cmd / rl_wheel_.rads_per_count / cfg_.loop_rate);
//  arduino_.setMotorValues(rr_wheel_.cmd / rr_wheel_.rads_per_count / cfg_.loop_rate, rl_wheel_.cmd / rl_wheel_.rads_per_count / cfg_.loop_rate);




  return return_type::OK;


  
}



#include "pluginlib/class_list_macros.hpp"

PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(
  DiffDriveArduino,
  hardware_interface::SystemInterface
)

diffdrive_robot.cpp:
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <controller_manager/controller_manager.h>
#include "diffdrive_arduino/diffdrive_arduino.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "diffdrive_robot");
  ros::NodeHandle n("~");

  DiffDriveArduino::Config robot_cfg;

  // Attempt to retrieve parameters. If they don't exist, the default values from the struct will be used
  n.getParam("FL_wheel_name", robot_cfg.FL_wheel_name);
  n.getParam("FR_wheel_name", robot_cfg.FR_wheel_name);
  n.getParam("RL_wheel_name", robot_cfg.RL_wheel_name);
  n.getParam("RR_wheel_name", robot_cfg.RR_wheel_name);
  n.getParam("baud_rate", robot_cfg.baud_rate);
  n.getParam("device", robot_cfg.device);
  n.getParam("enc_counts_per_rev", robot_cfg.enc_counts_per_rev);
  n.getParam("robot_loop_rate", robot_cfg.loop_rate);
  

  DiffDriveArduino robot(robot_cfg);
  controller_manager::ControllerManager cm(&robot);

  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();

  ros::Time prevTime = ros::Time::now();

  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

  while (ros::ok())
  {
    robot.read();
    cm.update(robot.get_time(), robot.get_period());
    robot.write();

    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
}

arduino_comms.cpp:
#include "diffdrive_arduino/arduino_comms.h"
// #include <ros/console.h>
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>


void ArduinoComms::setup(const std::string &serial_device, int32_t baud_rate, int32_t timeout_ms)
{  
    serial_conn_.setPort(serial_device);
    serial_conn_.setBaudrate(baud_rate);
    serial::Timeout tt = serial::Timeout::simpleTimeout(timeout_ms);
    serial_conn_.setTimeout(tt); // This should be inline except setTimeout takes a reference and so needs a variable
    serial_conn_.open();
    // serial_conn_.(serial_device, baud_rate, serial::Timeout::simpleTimeout(timeout_ms));

}


void ArduinoComms::sendEmptyMsg()
{
    std::string response = sendMsg("\r");
}

void ArduinoComms::readEncoderValues(int &val_1, int &val_2)
{
    std::string response = sendMsg("e\r");

    std::string delimiter = " ";
    size_t del_pos = response.find(delimiter);
    std::string token_1 = response.substr(0, del_pos);
    std::string token_2 = response.substr(del_pos + delimiter.length());

    val_1 = std::atoi(token_1.c_str());
    val_2 = std::atoi(token_2.c_str());
}

void ArduinoComms::setMotorValues(int val_1, int val_2)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "m " << val_1 << " " << val_2 << "\r";
    sendMsg(ss.str(), false);
}

void ArduinoComms::setPidValues(float k_p, float k_d, float k_i, float k_o)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "u " << k_p << ":" << k_d << ":" << k_i << ":" << k_o << "\r";
    sendMsg(ss.str());
}

std::string ArduinoComms::sendMsg(const std::string &msg_to_send, bool print_output)
{
    serial_conn_.write(msg_to_send);
    std::string response = serial_conn_.readline();

    if (print_output)
    {
        // RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(logger_,"Sent: " << msg_to_send);
        // RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(logger_,"Received: " << response);
    }

    return response;
}

diffdrive_arduino.h:
#ifndef DIFFDRIVE_ARDUINO_REAL_ROBOT_H
#define DIFFDRIVE_ARDUINO_REAL_ROBOT_H

#include <cstring>
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

#include "hardware_interface/base_interface.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/system_interface.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/handle.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/hardware_info.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/types/hardware_interface_return_values.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/types/hardware_interface_status_values.hpp"

#include "config.h"
#include "wheel.h"
#include "arduino_comms.h"


using hardware_interface::return_type;

class DiffDriveArduino : public hardware_interface::BaseInterface<hardware_interface::SystemInterface>
{


public:
  DiffDriveArduino();

  return_type configure(const hardware_interface::HardwareInfo & info) override;

  std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> export_state_interfaces() override;

  std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> export_command_interfaces() override;

  return_type start() override;

  return_type stop() override;

  return_type read() override;

  return_type write() override;



private:

  Config cfg_;
  ArduinoComms arduino_;

  Wheel fl_wheel_;
  Wheel fr_wheel_;
  Wheel rl_wheel_;
  Wheel rr_wheel_;

  rclcpp::Logger logger_;

  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> time_;
  
};


#endif // DIFFDRIVE_ARDUINO_REAL_ROBOT_H

arduino_comms.h:
#ifndef DIFFDRIVE_ARDUINO_ARDUINO_COMMS_H
#define DIFFDRIVE_ARDUINO_ARDUINO_COMMS_H

#include <serial/serial.h>
#include <cstring>

class ArduinoComms
{


public:

  ArduinoComms()
  {  }

  ArduinoComms(const std::string &serial_device, int32_t baud_rate, int32_t timeout_ms)
      : serial_conn_(serial_device, baud_rate, serial::Timeout::simpleTimeout(timeout_ms))
  {  }

  void setup(const std::string &serial_device, int32_t baud_rate, int32_t timeout_ms);
  void sendEmptyMsg();
  void readEncoderValues(int &val_1, int &val_2);
  void setMotorValues(int val_1, int val_2);
  void setPidValues(float k_p, float k_d, float k_i, float k_o);

  bool connected() const { return serial_conn_.isOpen(); }

  std::string sendMsg(const std::string &msg_to_send, bool print_output = false);


private:
  serial::Serial serial_conn_;  ///< Underlying serial connection 
};

#endif // DIFFDRIVE_ARDUINO_ARDUINO_COMMS_H

There are other files but these are the important ones. Also, this is my ros2_control.xacro file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    
    <xacro:unless value="$(arg sim_mode)">
        <ros2_control name="RobotSystem" type="system">
            <hardware>
                <plugin>diffdrive_arduino/DiffDriveArduino</plugin>
                <param name="FL_wheel_name">FL_wheel_joint</param>
                <param name="FR_wheel_name">FR_wheel_joint</param>
                <param name="RL_wheel_name">RL_wheel_joint</param>
                <param name="RR_wheel_name">RR_wheel_joint</param>
                <param name="loop_rate">30</param>
                <param name="device">/dev/ttyACM0</param>
                <param name="baud_rate">57600</param>
                <param name="timeout">1000</param>
                <param name="enc_counts_per_rev">3436</param>
            </hardware>
            <joint name="FL_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="FR_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="RL_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="RR_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
        </ros2_control>
    </xacro:unless>

    <xacro:if value="$(arg sim_mode)">
        <ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
            <hardware>
                <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
            </hardware>
            <joint name="FL_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="FR_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="RL_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="RR_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
        </ros2_control>
    </xacro:if>
    
    <gazebo>
        <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
            <parameters>$(find robot)/config/my_controllers.yaml</parameters>
        <parameters>$(find robot)/config/gaz_ros2_ctl_use_sim.yaml</parameters>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

</robot>

EXTRA INFO: when pressing l or j in teleop_twist_keyboard, the motors seem to "hesitate" or first turn to one side then the other, as if there were conflicting messages. Running miniterm and inputting raw commands (e.g. "o 255 -255") is able to move the wheels in opposite directions correctly.
Any help is highly appreciated.

I managed to solve the problem by turning
  arduino_.setMotorValues(fl_wheel_.cmd / fl_wheel_.rads_per_count / cfg_.loop_rate, rl_wheel_.cmd / rl_wheel_.rads_per_count / cfg_.loop_rate);
//  arduino_.setMotorValues(rr_wheel_.cmd / rr_wheel_.rads_per_count / cfg_.loop_rate, rl_wheel_.cmd / rl_wheel_.rads_per_count / cfg_.loop_rate);

into
  arduino_.setMotorValues(fl_wheel_.cmd / fl_wheel_.rads_per_count / cfg_.loop_rate, fr_wheel_.cmd / fr_wheel_.rads_per_count / cfg_.loop_rate);

Basically just ignoring the rear wheel commands, which, in my setup, are the same as the front ones. I had already commented out half of them, just the wrong ones.
